# How can I add .NET namespace information in DocFX

Tags: docfx

The title says it all ...

In Sandcastle Help File Builder we added the [`NamespaceDoc`](https://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB/html/48f5a893-acde-4e50-8c17-72b83d9c3f9d.htm) class to each namespace to create namespace documentation.

How do we to the same using DocFX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to add it directly in source code. You can use [overwrite files](http://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/intro_overwrite_files.html) to add summary for namespace type.

Answer (score 16):

Here's how I did it:

1. In the root folder of your documentation project, add a folder named **namespaces**.
2. Update your **docfx.json** file to include markup files added to the **namespaces** folder.  You need to update the **overwrite** property in the **build** section.  It will look something like this:

```json
    "overwrite": [
      {
        "files": [
          "apidoc/**.md",
          "namespaces/**.md"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "obj/**",
          "_site/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
```

3. Create a markdown file in the **namespaces** folder for every namespace you want to add documentation to. It is probably best to name these files the same as the namespace.

   The files should have a YAML header with a UID that matches the namespace's name.  The **summary: *content** line tells docfx to *overwrite* the summary of the namespace with the contents of this file.

   The rest of the page is standard markdown that will become the namespace's summary.  For example:

   > ---
   >   uid: My.Groovy.Namespace
   >   summary: *content
   >   ---
   >   The My.Groovy.Namespace namespace contains a bunch of classes and interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably extremely late to this question, but i faced a similar problem and the solution i found invovles modifying docfx from source and adding helping classes, much like `Sandcastle`'s solution.

> #### Disclamer:
>
> I do not claim that the solution i'm showcasing is programmatically
> stable, safe or even correct. I do not claim that this solution will
> work in any scenario or for any use. I only verify that, for me, it
> worked perfectly fine, even though i recongize it's just a fast-put-up
> workaround.

## Steps :

1. I downloaded the source code of docfx from their github's [releases](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/releases/latest) page (2.59.2, as of today)

---

2. After extracting the solution, I opened the file `docfx-2.59.2\src\Microsoft.DocAsCode.Metadata.ManagedReference\ExtractMetadataWorker.cs`

---

3. The class implemented within this file contains a method named `GetMetadataFromProjectLevelCache` that, at some point, extracts the metadata
   from the referenced project in a tree form.

```cs
private Tuple<MetadataItem, bool> GetMetadataFromProjectLevelCache(IBuildController controller, IInputParameters key){
   // [...]
   projectMetadata = controller.ExtractMetadata(key); // THIS line
   // [...]
}
```

---

4. After this line, I appended the following line containing a method which I also had to implement.

```cs
private Tuple<MetadataItem, bool> GetMetadataFromProjectLevelCache(IBuildController controller, IInputParameters key){
   // [...]
   projectMetadata = controller.ExtractMetadata(key);
   ExtractNamespaceDocumentation(projectMetadata); // THIS line
   // [...]
}
```

---

5. The implementation was the following:

```cs
private void ExtractNamespaceDocumentation(MetadataItem node)
{
    // Terminal nodes are not of our interest in any case
    // Even if it's a namespace, it does not contain documentation
    if (node.Items is not { Count: > 0 }) return;
    
    // If it is namespace
    if (node.Type == MemberType.Namespace)
    {
        // Get (if any), the child that is class and is named "_NamespaceDoc"
        var doc = node.Items.FirstOrDefault(x =>
            x.Type == MemberType.Class && x.Name.Split('.').Last() == "_NamespaceDoc");

        // If we didn't found such class, the namespace does not contain documentation.
        // Leave and don't go further.
        if (doc is null) return;

        // Else, assign the class' Summary and remarks to the Namespace and remove the class from the tree.
        node.Summary = doc.Summary;
        node.Remarks = doc.Remarks;
        node.Items.Remove(doc);

        // job finished for this namespace, we do not want to go further down the tree.
        return;
    }

    // For non-namespace intermediate nodes (IE assembly nodes), visit the children.
    foreach (var child in node.Items) ExtractNamespaceDocumentation(child);
}
```

---

6. Lastly, I compiled the solution and, by using the newly created `docfx.exe` located at `docfx-2.59.2\src\docfx\bin\Debug\net472`, i was able to detect all classes named `_NamespaceDoc` and use their `<summary>` tags to fill the namespaces they resided.

---

For the record, i decided to create a new `.cs` file at the root of my project to contain all `_NamespaceDoc` classes, so it would be easier for me to disable the whole file when i want to release the project. This file looked like this:

```cs
namespace RootNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Documentation for the Root Namespace
    /// </summary>
    public static class _NamespaceDoc { }
}

namespace RootNamespace.SubFolder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Documentation for the Root Namespace's `SubFolder` Sub-Namespace.
    /// </summary>
    public static class _NamespaceDoc { }
}

// [...]
```

Hopefully, this may help other fellows seaking for such solution, or even the `docfx` devs and contributors to implement this feature more reliably.

---

#### **Update:**

For more info about this approach, I've started a [discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/discussions/7990)
on docfx's github repository

Comment: Wow!  … Would you consider creating a pull request from this to the repository?

Comment: I already started a [discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/discussions/7990) on docfx github repo, but it seems like all development is focused to release/bugfix V3, instead of adding features to the current stable release